# How to find first data column where data exist & remove unwanted rows, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have total 343 data frame with different column structure. I want to find text from first row of first occurring column.
Actual data in excel file:
[image]

Expected Results:

firstRowtext: **Q60h. As I read each one, please tell me if**

output df(with column name as column 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7):
[image]

Comment: Try it and show us the code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need read each file twice - first for first value and skipped rows and then again with parameter `skiprows`:

```
files = glob.glob('data\*.xlsx')

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, index_col=False)
    val = df.columns[0].split()[0]
    print (val)
    pos = df.iloc[:, 0].notnull().idxmax() + 1
    df = pd.read_excel(f, skiprows=pos, header=None).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```